# Mixing 15K rpm SAS with 7.2K rpm SATA on Dell PowerEdge R610

Tags: sas, sata

Is it possible to mix 15K rpm SAS with 7.2K rpm SATA on Dell PowerEdge R610 on the same RAID configuration (Raid 5)?
Is the SAS' speed going to drop to follow the lowest speed (the SATA speed)?
and the storage cap, is it going to drop to the lowest?

thanks

Answer (score 6):

No, you may not mix drive types in the *same* array level. You have have separate arrays comprised of SATA and SAS drives in the same chassis, though.

Edit: this applies to hardware RAID. I'm sure you can use any combination you wish in a software RAID setup.